# Datatable, Yadcf and Select2. How do you add Select2 filters outside of the table

Tags: datatable, jquery-select2, yadcf

I am using Datatables, Yadcf and Select2. I have an Error as soon as I click on any filter. The error is. The select2('close') method was called on an element that is not using Select2. Unable to get property 'close' of undefined or null reference. I have placed the select2 cdn above the yadcf cdn. I placed an example here. Watch the console. https://jsfiddle.net/Paul2167/zusvc4ra/
I am using filters that sit outside of the table. I only have 2 filters. If they are both of type select2 then there is no error. But if only 1 filter is set to use select2. Then the error occurs when clicking either filter.

This is the html snippet

```
    <div>
      <span id="external_filter_container1">
      <!-- leave the wrapper contents empty -->
      </span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <span id="external_filter_container2">
      <!-- leave the wrapper contents empty -->
      </span>
    </div>

    <div>
    <table class="mytable2 display table">
      <tbody>
      //table data...
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

My datatable init file is here:

```
    var oTable;
    jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
      'use strict';

     // start datatable
    oTable = $('.mytable2').DataTable( {
        pageLength: 10,
        searching: true
     });
    // end datatable

    // start yadcf
    yadcf.init(oTable, 
     [
      {
       column_number : 0,
       filter_container_id: 'external_filter_container1',
       filter_reset_button_text: false,
       select_type: 'select2',
       filter_default_label: 'First'

       },
      {
       column_number : 1, 
       filter_container_id: 'external_filter_container2',
       filter_reset_button_text: false,
       //select_type: 'select2',
       filter_default_label: 'Last'
       }
      ]
     );
    // end yadcf

    }); // end ready function
```

Comment: will be fixed in 0.9.4.beta.12

Comment: @Daniel Thank you. I found it here. https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/500

Answer (score 0):

This is already fixed in version already fixed in 0.9.4.beta.12 which has not been released yet. github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/500